# Google's oauth2 endpoint - v1 vs v2 changes?

Tags: google-api, hapi.js, google-oauth

I know that this is something like a 'RTFM' question, but I can't for the life of me find solid documentation about this.

Specifically, I have a service that uses google's oauth2 REST api to authenticate users. The library I'm using ([bell](https://github.com/hapijs/bell)), recently started making calls to the /v2 version of the API endpoint. Those calls no longer seem to support `approval_prompt=force` in the querystring (or something along those lines, I'm no longer able to use a special route to force a new refresh token).

Realistically, all I need to do is read the documentation for what changed from v1 to v2 of the oauth2 library, or even find v2-specific information. All the documentation on developers.google.com seems to be about the v1 api.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no documented list of changes at present.  The main changes from`/auth` to `v2/auth`, and `v3/token` to `v4/token` is that the newer versions are [certified](http://openid.net/certification) compliant with [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).  The earlier versions had a few inconsistencies with the spec, mostly because when Google launched them the spec was not yet final.

`approval_prompt` is now `prompt`. To get your `approval_prompt=force` behavior on the newer endpoint, specify `prompt=consent`. Other values for the `prompt` parameter are defined in [section 3.1.2.1](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.section.3.1.2.1) of the spec.

Other changes, in no particular order:

1. the ID Token `iss` value is now `https://accounts.google.com`, was `accounts.google.com`
2. `nonce` is required for implicit and hybrid flows
3. ID tokens on the newer endpoints [may contain profile claims](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32406589/72176) (if the `profile` scope was requested), saving a call to userinfo.