# OAuth - Can I get Google user photo via user id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

In Facebook, I can get user photo by using user id, like this:

> ```
> var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
> ```
>
> string pictureUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + info.Login.ProviderKey + "/picture?type=large";

Is it possible in Google? If possible, can you give me the url which I can get user photo with `ProviderKey`?

something's like:

> string pictureUrl = "https://google.com/" + info.Login.ProviderKey +
>   "/picture?type=large";

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use the `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` endpoint and pass a bearer token which is just the access token provided during the OAuth login.

See: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the newer auth endpoints (`v2/auth` and `v4/token` as referenced in the [discovery document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery)) and request the `profile` scope in your auth request, the returned ID Token will include user photo in the `picture` claim, for users that have one.  This question has [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32406589/72176).